# Filter the output of GNU nm by section

Tags: elf, binutils, nm

I'm trying to identify the largest symbols in an `.elf` file for each memory section (.text, .data, .bss). So far I'm using [GNU nm](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.33.1/binutils/nm.html#nm) to get the largest symbols:

```sh
nm foo.elf --size-sort --reverse-sort --radix=d --demangle --line-numbers
```

Is there a builtin way in nm to filter the ouput by section or do I need to resort to text filtering?

nm outputs a section type for every symbol as single letter code (B: .bss, D: .data, T: .text), but there seems no way to filter by symbol type.

**Background:** The code runs on a microcontroller which is able to execute instruction directly from flash memory. The instructions from the .text section stay in the flash memory during execution, .bss and .data are loaded into the RAM. That's way I would like to be able to identify the largest symbols in each section independently.

Comment: Why would you not use the map file generated by the linker?  Using nm is a bit "reverse-engineering" when you would have had the information first hand.

Comment: You have "over tagged" this issue.  The fact that the target the map refers to is an embedded microcontroller is largely irrelevant, as is elf  - it is just a text processing issue that many can answer.  An _"easy way"_ is subjective making it way too broad.

Comment: @Clifford I removed the embedded and microcontroller tags.

Comment: @Clifford Do you know of any tool that can find the largest symbols sorted by section from a .map file? That was actually what I tried first, but both tools I looked at ([AMAP](http://www.sikorskiy.net/prj/amap/) and [MapViewer](https://github.com/govind-mukundan/MapViewer)) don't offer the possibility to  sort by section and size. Of course I could write a script for that purpose, but why build a new tool if I can just use nm?

Comment: Because building a new tool may have taken less time that you have spent on this question already.  Paste the content into a spreadsheet and sort it is by advice.  https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there seems no way to filter by symbol type.

Just use `grep` to perform any filtering you may need.

You may also want to look at [Bloaty McBloatface: a size profiler for binaries](https://github.com/google/bloaty#bloaty-mcbloatface-a-size-profiler-for-binaries).

Comment: Thanks, sometimes it's hard to see the solution although good ol' grep is right in front of your nose. I used the following one liner in the end:

`nm foo.elf --size-sort --reverse-sort --radix=d --demangle --line-numbers | grep -i " t " | less`

`grep -i " t "`will filter for all symbols in the .text section (the filtering could probably be made more elegantly using a regex).